# Is there a MDB(modular debugger) solaris equivalent in Linux?

Tags: linux, debugging, memory-management, memory-leaks, linux-kernel

Could anyone let me know if there is a tool which is an equivalent for the mdb(modular debugger, Solaris) in Linux. I just got the Libumem port for Linux. Now if I could find an equivalent for MDB in Linux, I would be a great deal to find the leaks in my code.